# installing amqp on mac with brew

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, amqp, pecl

I wanted to install `amqp` with pecl for my mac sierra.

I installed php with brew, with `pecl install amqp` I receive an error: `checking for amqp using pkg-config... configure: error: librabbitmq not found`

I installed with brew the `librabbitmq-c` package but I still get this error. I think it's somehow not synced with the pkg-config.

Does someone have an idea what to do here?

Answer (score 95):

First install rabbitmq-c with brew:

```
brew search librabbitmq
No formula or cask found for "librabbitmq".
Closed pull requests:
Add rabbitmq-c (aka librabbitmq) formula (https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/pull/13437)


brew install rabbitmq-c
```

Then install amqp with pecl:

```
pecl install amqp
```

Set the path to librabbitmq:

```
Set the path to librabbitmq install prefix [autodetect] : /usr/local/Cellar/rabbitmq-c/0.9.0
```

Verify that amqp is now installed:

```
php -i|grep amqp
```

Comment: Although `php -i | grep amqp` didn't return any info confirming amqp was enabled, I was able to use it.

Comment: @dmd Maybe you forgot to add extension=amqp.so; to you php.ini file
Pecl do it automatically but you must specify the location of your php.ini

To set the location: pecl config-set php_ini /usr/local/etc/php/7.xxx/php.ini
Check php.ini location file : php --ini

Comment: php -m | grep amqp

Comment: @jose answer worked for me on MacOS Big Sur with PHP 7.2.

Comment: Works fine on Big Sur, just path to cellar has changed:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rabbitmq-c/0.11.0

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for this walk through, it was super helpful. Just a quick note, in Mac OS 12.0.1 Monterey, the default install path for rabbitmq in homebrew is:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rabbitmq-c/0.11.0
```

Comment: Actually for me (Monterey 12.3.1) it is `/usr/local/Cellar/rabbitmq-c/0.11.0`

Answer (score 3):

I'm on MacOS High Sierra. I installed the Command_line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_10.1.dmg from developer.apple.com and brew installed php 8.

For the amqp extension, I used:

```
brew install rabbitmq-c
pecl install amqp-1.11.0beta
```

at the prompt

> Set the path to librabbitmq install prefix [autodetect] :

I entered:

> Set the path to librabbitmq install prefix [autodetect] : /usr/local/Cellar/rabbitmq-c/0.11.0

Comment: I also had to run `mkdir -p /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl`

Answer (score 2):

The issue lies with pkg-config not being able to generate libs/cflags for librabbitmq.

```
$ pkg-config librabbitmq --cflags
Package openssl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `openssl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'openssl', required by 'librabbitmq', not found
```

What I did was to add both **rabbitmq-c** and **openssl** to **$PKG_CONFIG_PATH** as below:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/rabbitmq-c/0.10.0/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Then the build will succeed. (Note: I built mine with phpbrew rather than pecl, but should work).

Answer (score 1):

Brew doesn't add the file to the pkg-config path, so it needed a command:
`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/rabbitmq-c/0.9.0/lib/pkgconfig"`

Comment: didn't help though :-/

Answer (score 1):

Before installing make sure the taps are up-to-date:

```
brew update
```

Then, install RabbitMQ server with:

```
brew install rabbitmq
```

In case that directory is not in PATH it's recommended to append it:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a combination of question and both previous answers which worked for me.

First install RabbitMQ through brew as rabbitmq-c. Then with PECL but add the config path when asked: `/usr/local/Cellar/rabbitmq-c/0.10.0`

Needs to be adjusted with your installed brew version of RabbitMQ.

Comment: This didn't work for me. ```pecl config-set php_ini /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php.ini``` and brew install rabbitmq-c and pecl install amqp it still can't find amqp.so

Answer (score 0):

On my M1 Mac Pro, PHP 8.2.1 the PECL install amqp rabbbitmq path it wanted is /opt/homebrew/Cellar/rabbitmq-c/0.11.0/

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).